# Dialogflow / Error after two incorrect messages (keywords)

Tags: dialogflow-es

There is an intent, when the user writes messages to the bot (a certain word), it goes further follow-up intent. When the keyword is incorrect, the answer is given from the default fallback intent. The problem is that when you write a keyword twice incorrectly, it finds everything wrong.

Sorry for bad english

Comment: With this statement, I am unable to understand the situation. Better if you post your Dialogflow structure here, so it would be easy to debug further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try increasing the lifespan of the context. I guess it might be set to 2 because when you the bot goes to fallback 2 times, then context expires.

You can try to set the output context of your follow up intent in the fallback intent as well but that is not a good solution.